# reCaptcha installation issues

Tags: html, perl, captcha, recaptcha

Ok so here's my issue with trying to install the reCaptcha. On my basic HTML page I have the following form in the body of the content.

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/new_forms/form.pl" method="post" name="pledgeform" onSubmit="return validate(this)">

This is where all the form info is

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"> &nbsp; <input type="reset" value="Clear Form"></p>
</form>
```

Now I know that I need to place this Google code just above my submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
</script>
<noscript>
   <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key"
       height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
   <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
   </textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
       value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

My issue is where do I go from here? I know that it needs to verify the reCaptcha but I currently have the form going to a Perl script so I'm confused. Can I have it so that the reCaptcha needs to be correct first in order for the action to go and run the Perl script? I'm not sure if I'm asking this correctly so if anyone needs any other info let me know. I'm stumped and any help would be awesome.

*My skill level is basic-intermediate just so you know where I'm coming from*

Answer (score 1):

[`Captcha::reCAPTCHA`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Captcha%3a%3areCAPTCHA) has documentation on its use.

There is also an [`example CGI script`](https://metacpan.org/source/PHRED/Captcha-reCAPTCHA-0.97/examples/captcha.pl) included in the package.

Basically, yes, you need to stay on the form in order to error check that the captcha was actually filled in correctly, just like with all form error checking.

Comment: So am I to put that script above the rest of my code in my form.pl file then? 
The form.pl file currently takes all the info from the form and emails it to a specific person (if that needs to be known?)

Comment: Yes. Some code similar to the one in the script can be added to the form.pl and not necessarily above the rest of the code in it.